# Is it possible to highlight only the text of the current QComboBox Selection?

Tags: qt, selection, highlight, qcombobox, selectedtext

I want only text of the current QComboBox Selection to be highlighted instead of the whole area

until the down arrow. to illustrate better I want something like this:
[image]

instead of this: [image]

Is this possible? If yes how? I searched online, tried a couple of things but cannot make it work. Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is the default behavior for an *editable* combo box. In that case, simply set

```
QComboBox* box = new QComboBox();
box->setEditable(true);
```

If you don't want your `QComboBox` to be editable, then it's unintuitive, but what you want to do can still be accomplished.

If you set the `QComboBox` to be editable, *while setting the underlying line edit to be read only*, then the highlighting will look like in your picture, but there won't be any cursor and the user won't be able to edit the combo box items. Here's an example:

```
QComboBox* box = new QComboBox();
box->addItems(QStringList() << "None (Min Profit)" << "All (Max Profit)");
box->setEditable(true);
box->lineEdit()->setReadOnly(true);

// c++11 style, but this can also be done using SIGNAL(...) and SLOT(...)
connect(box, static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::activated), [box]
{
    box->lineEdit()->selectAll();
});
```

And here's an image of the result (I'm on Windows 10 so the styling is a bit funny)

[image: Working combobox]

*My 2 cents*: While it can be done, the default Qt highlighting scheme may be more intuitive to your users for non-editable items.

Comment: Since Qt 5.7 and C++14, you can use [qOverload](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload) which is more readable than a `static_cast` in your `connect`:

`connect(box, qOverload<int>(&QComboBox::activated), [box] { box->lineEdit()->selectAll(); });`